# Extremely slow and unstable WiFi connection using TP-Link TL W727N

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

The TP-Link TL W727N(V3) WiFi adapter works extremely slow while using Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. I always see a weak connection, and it tends to get disconnected at times. I have a dual booted Windows 10 on my PC, but the adapter works perfectly fine there. I have turned the power management for this adapter, but that did not seem to help much. Those problems still persist. Please suggest me what to do.

Here is the dump for `iwconfig`-

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Riad Rezaul Wi-FI"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: EC:08:6B:30:53:62   
          Bit Rate=60 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:443  Invalid misc:804   Missed beacon:0
```

And the dump for `sudo lshw -C network`-

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1.1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 90:f6:52:0d:bd:84
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.13.0-106-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.0.105 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Is connectivity improved with 802.11N turned off in your router?

Comment: No it remains exactly the same after disabling 802.11N mode.

Comment: May we see some logs? `dmesg | grep rt2` As the output will be lengthy, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hello @chili555 here it is- http://paste.ubuntu.com/23707437/

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the message in your log:

> rt2800usb_txdone: Warning - Got TX status for an empty queue 2,
>   dropping

...returns many hits and no real solution. I suggest that you check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router. In many cases, rt2800xx devices seem to work much better with the router set to B and G speeds only. After trying these changes, in each case, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800usb
sudo modprobe rt2800usb nohwcrypt=Y
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=Y"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
exit
```

Comment: Applying `sudo iw reg set IS` seems to have seriously weakened the Link Quality of the connection. I can barely go online now. Also, applying the `modprobe` commands disconnect the WiFi connection, that I could not get back without restarting the computer.

Comment: Did you read the instructions? "Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland."  The modprobe is *supposed* to disconnect the wireless until you do the following, hopefully improved, modprobe.

Comment: My bad, I did put my country code `BD` at that place before applying it. But as I mentioned, no improvement unfortunately. Could it be something relating the driver for the chipset? I looked it up, but could not find a proprietary driver for RT5370.